# POI - get.hyperlink() is not retrieving the latest hyperlink of a cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Here I'm overwriting a the 1st hyperlink with 2nd hyperlink in a same cell and `get.hyperlink()` method is always pulling the hyperlink that was first written in a cell.

Any help around this would be great!! Thanks in advance

Below is my code and output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExcelUtils2.writeHyperLink("DashboardCopy", 1, 1, "test1", "https://google.com");
    ExcelUtils2.writeHyperLink("DashboardCopy", 1, 1, "test2", "https://facebook.com");
    String dtr = ExcelUtils2.getCellHyperlink(1, 1);
    System.out.println("Hyperlink of the cell is >> " + dtr);
}


public static synchronized void writeHyperLink(String workBookName, int irow, int icol, String ivalue, String iUrl)
        throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
    FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(excelSource);
    excelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
    excelWSheet = excelWBook.getSheet(workBookName);
    createHelper = excelWBook.getCreationHelper();
    XSSFRow row = excelWSheet.getRow(irow);
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(icol);
    cell.setCellValue(ivalue);
    XSSFHyperlink link = (XSSFHyperlink) createHelper.createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL);
    link.setAddress(iUrl);
    cell.setHyperlink(link);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelSource);
    excelWBook.write(fos);
    fos.close();

}

public static String getCellHyperlink(int rowNum, int colNum) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(excelSource);
    excelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
    excelWSheet = excelWBook.getSheet("DashboardCopy");
    XSSFRow row = excelWSheet.getRow(rowNum);
    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(colNum);
    XSSFHyperlink link = cell.getHyperlink();
    String cellData = link.getAddress();
    // System.out.println(link.getAddress());
    return cellData;
}
```

Output:
Hyperlink of the cell is >> https://google.com

Expected Output:
It should print https://facebook.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try and remove the hyperlink before setting it

```
 cell.removeHyperlink();
 cell.setHyperlink(link);
```

Comment: how about doing excelWBook.close() at the end of writeHyperLink?

Comment: Note though, It correctly writes "facebook.com" if we take the address in writeHyperLink method using link.getAddress() after it writes the link in a cell. Problem occurs only if we use getHyperlink() method.

Comment: It worked with the removeHyperlink() method - Used it before it writes the new Hyperlink